# KineticJS: Defining offset and rotation using anchors

Tags: kineticjs

I'm new to KineticJS and I am trying to use anchors in order to rotate and image about the centre point, which is defined using a separate anchor.

I have the rotation working and the defining the centre of rotation working also. However when the user drags the anchor to define the centre of rotation, i use the setOffset() function and it causes the image to move instead of the anchor.

I was wondering if there's a way to allow the user to drag the anchor and the anchor moves and sets the Offset instead of a user dragging the anchor and the image moves?

The update function is as follows

```
function update(group, activeAnchor) {
var topLeft = group.get(".topLeft")[0];
var topRight = group.get(".topRight")[0];
var bottomRight = group.get(".bottomRight")[0];
var bottomLeft = group.get(".bottomLeft")[0];
var centre = group.get(".centre")[0];
var image = group.get(".image")[0];

var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

var centreX = group.getOffsetX();
var centreY = group.getOffsetY();

var width = group.getWidth();
var height = group.getHeight();
// update anchor positions
switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
     case 'topLeft':
          topRight.setY(anchorY);
          bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
          centreX = topLeft.getX()/2;
          centreY = topLeft.getY()/2;
          break;

    case 'topRight':
          topLeft.setY(anchorY);
          bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
          centreX = topRight.getX()/2;
          centreY = topRight.getY()/2;
          break;

    case 'bottomRight':
          bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
          topRight.setX(anchorX);
          break;

    case 'bottomLeft':
          bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
          topLeft.setX(anchorX);

          centre.setX(centreX);
          centre.setY(centreY);
          break;

    case "centre":
          var absolute = group.getPosition();
          group.setOffset(anchorX, anchorY);
          group.setPosition(absolute);
  }

image.setPosition(topLeft.attrs.x, topLeft.attrs.y);

var width = topRight.attrs.x - topLeft.attrs.x;
var height = bottomLeft.attrs.y - topLeft.attrs.y;
if(width && height) {
    image.setSize(width, height);
 }
}
```

I'm also trying to update the centre of rotation a sthe four corners of the image in resizing when dragged. Any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/njPdr/ (It may not work properly here but you can see what I am trying to do here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the position of the image with: `image.setPosition(topLeft.attrs.x, topLeft.attrs.y);`

If you replace it by `image.setOffset(youroffsetx, youroffsety);` the image will no longer move and you will set an offset like you wanted to do.
About your second question, remember that the offset is the center of rotation.

Edit as discussed in comments:

```
case "centre":
          var absolute = group.getPosition();
          group.setOffset(anchorX, anchorY);
          group.setPosition({x:absolute.x + group.getOffsetX(), y:absolute.y + group.getOffsetY()});
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help but unfortunately it doesnt work. The image is part of a group and the image.setPosition is required to have the image within the group (the four anchors) for resizing. If the image.setPosition is removed and replaced with image.setOffset, the image remains in the top left of the stage when the group is dragged.

Comment: Hi, can you send me a jsfiddle so I can see the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/njPdr/3 this is a full implementation. it may not work properly in the fiddle but you'll see what I am trying to do. The encoding or anything will not work. a copy of the js is in the javascript section but the js is used externally on my site which can be seen in the html under the external resources at kinetic.js

Comment: I see you are setting the offset and then you set the image position to its previous position, but then the image moves. Here is an explanation: when you set an element x and y positions in KineticJS, you set its offset position. It means that if you change this offset and want the image to remain at the same position, you have to add the offset to the previous position.
In case 'center' try this:
`group.setPosition({x:absolute.x + group.getOffsetX(), y:absolute.y + group.getOffsetY()});`

Comment: I've reflected your changes in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/njPdr/5/ and i updated it so edits in the javascript section will now work. I added your code to my local copy but it says that absolute is undefined and i got the x and y absolute coords from the group and used those but the image just jumps to the top left corner of the stage and is no longer draggable.

Comment: I was using `var absolute = group.getPosition();` based on your update function in your first post. I've edited my answer.

Comment: updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/njPdr/7/, image keeps jumping when offset is set and position set directly afterwards

Comment: Use console.log to check the position values right after group.setPosition(). If it jumps to 0,0 position there is something wrong here.
What version of KineticJS are you using? Because in newer versions you can't set several values like in `setOffset(value_x,value_y)`, you have to do `setOffset({x:value_x, y:value_y})`.

Comment: will do and i see. I'm using the latest version (it was a few months ago) which i think is 4.7.4. I'll give it a go there